# Может OrmLite автоматически создавать объекты ForeignCollectionField в базе данных?

Tags: java, json, ormlite

Предположим, у меня есть классы Order и Account (как в документации)

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "orders")
public class Order {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;    
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true)
    private Account account; 
    ...
}   

public class Account {
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    ForeignCollection<Order> orders;
}
```

Допустим, я десериализую класс Account из файла вместе со всеми orders. 
Как сделать так, чтобы при создании десериализованного Account автоматически создавались также orders и не приходилось делать еще кучу запросов к Dao?

Comment: вы его десериализуете? или из БД извлекаете?